SQL Column to show value based on other column
I have 2 tables:

Activity table (Order Number, Event Name)
Order table (Order Number, Order status)

I want to get something like this:



Order Number
Activity Valid
Column C




1
if event name =x, then show y
if activity_valid=y then show Z



SQL code:
with table_1 as
(
    select Order_Number, Event_Name
    from Activity
),
Table_2 as
(
    select order_Number, Order_Status
    from Order
)
select 
    A.Order_Number, 
    if (Event_Name = x, Y, Y1) as Activity_Valid
    if (Activity_Valid = Y, Z, Z1) as Column C
from 
    Table_1 A 
left join 
    Table_2 B on A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number

The syntax for column C is invalid. What is the correct syntax for this?

It look like you can't reference calculated columns in a calculated column. In Column C, just replace "Activity_Valid=Y" with "Event_Name=x" as logically they are the same

To achieve the desired outcome where the second CASE statement depends on the result of the first CASE statement, you need to use a subquery or Common Table Expression (CTE) to compute the first CASE result and then use that result in the second CASE statement. Here's how you can structure the query:

Use a CTE or subquery to compute Activity_Valid.
Use another CTE or subquery to compute Column_C based on
Activity_Valid.

Here's the updated query using a CTE to achieve this:
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT Order_Number,
           Event_Name
    FROM Activity
),
table_2 AS (
    SELECT Order_Number,
           Order_Status
    FROM [Order]
),
cte_ActivityValid AS (
    SELECT 
        A.Order_Number, 
        A.Event_Name,
        CASE 
            WHEN A.Event_Name = 'x' THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'Y1' 
        END AS Activity_Valid
    FROM 
        table_1 A 
    LEFT JOIN 
        table_2 B
    ON 
        A.Order_Number = B.Order_Number
)

SELECT 
    cte.Order_Number, 
    cte.Activity_Valid,
    CASE 
        WHEN cte.Activity_Valid = 'Y' THEN 'Z' 
        ELSE 'Z1' 
    END AS Column_C
FROM 
    cte_ActivityValid cte;



@mohammed Kamel
CASE
WHEN Event_Name = 'y' THEN 'Z'
ELSE 'Z1'
but event name doesnt contain Y, y is the result of the 1st if

@EdbertSuryadi where the second CASE statement depends on the result of the first CASE statement, you need to use a subquery or Common Table Expression (CTE) to compute the first CASE result and then use that result in the second CASE statement.
The SQL statement updated
